# Is all bugtracking on stackoverflow public?

Tags: discussion

Maybe it isn't my business to know, but I am curious.

In the development process for each of these sites what bug tracking tools may have been used, besides user input. And how do you track feature requests for inclusion?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/does-the-so-development-team-use-fogbugz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow is the place to report bugs or feature requests (use either of the `bug` or `feature-request` tags).

Depending on the team's decision they will update with one of the following tags and possibly an answer or comment:

`status-bydesign`
`status-declined`
`status-planned`
`status-norepro`
`status-reproduced`
`status-completed`
`status-deferred`
`status-review`

Whether they use a private bug tracker internally such as FogBugz I couldn't possibly say.

Comment: Thanks. If a private bugtracking tool is used I might have taken it's use as an endorsement.